# Multi-textured floor rendering in 2D raycaster

Tags: c, sdl-2, raycasting

In this wonderful lodev's raycasting tutorial (https://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting2.html), we have a part about floor and ceiling.
I bet my problem is simple, but I can't help myself.

Using the horizontal method of rendering I want to render different textures for each tile on the map. In lodev's example we get `currentFloorX` and `currentFloorY`, but only using vertical rendering:

```
//draw the floor from drawEnd to the bottom of the screen
for(int y = drawEnd + 1; y < h; y++)
{
  currentDist = h / (2.0 * y - h); //you could make a small lookup table for this instead

  double weight = (currentDist - distPlayer) / (distWall - distPlayer);

  double currentFloorX = weight * floorXWall + (1.0 - weight) * posX;
  double currentFloorY = weight * floorYWall + (1.0 - weight) * posY;

  int floorTexX, floorTexY;
  floorTexX = int(currentFloorX * texWidth) % texWidth;
  floorTexY = int(currentFloorY * texHeight) % texHeight;
  ...
```

However, in the example for horizontal rendering we only get to calculate `tx` and `ty` for pixel positions on the texture:

```
for(int x = 0; x < screenWidth; ++x)
{
  // the cell coord is simply got from the integer parts of floorX and floorY
  int cellX = (int)(floorX);
  int cellY = (int)(floorY);

  // get the texture coordinate from the fractional part
  int tx = (int)(texWidth * (floorX - cellX)) & (texWidth - 1);
  int ty = (int)(texHeight * (floorY - cellY)) & (texHeight - 1);

  floorX += floorStepX;
  floorY += floorStepY;
  ...
```

I am not so good at trigonometry and only trying to understand these calculations. I've already tried various attempts with extracting integer and fractional parts of `tx` and `ty` mixed with map width and height. It resulted with total nonsense of `currentFloorX` and `currentFloorY` values and crashed, but sometimes produced really weird mosaic:

```
int currentFloorX = (int)((map->width & tx) * (floorX - cellX)) & (TEXTURE_SIZE -1);
int currentFloorY = (int)((map->height & ty) * (floorY - cellY)) & (TEXTURE_SIZE - 1);
```

[Resulted in mess like this 3 mixed textures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTiI1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess this post motivated me to spend some more time on this.

So, for anyone interested in the future, to obtain `currentFloorX` and `currentFloorY`:

```
int currentFloorX = cellX % mapWidth;
int currentFloorY = cellY % mapHeight;
```

and then, having separate floor like `floorMap` (same size as `worldMap`) you simply do:

```
int floorTexture = floorMap[currentFloorX][currentFloorY];
```